# How to check telegram channels for comments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I need to use pyrogram module to check the telegram channel for comments, I think the [GetGroupsForDiscussion](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/channels/get-groups-for-discussion#pyrogram.raw.functions.channels.GetGroupsForDiscussion) method should do it, but it doesn't want to accept arguments. And it's nonsense to make code that checks for an error when receiving the number of comments.

I wanted to pass a link to a channel to [GetGroupsForDiscussion](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/channels/get-groups-for-discussion#pyrogram.raw.functions.channels.GetGroupsForDiscussion), because the documentation does not say anything about this method, but the method does not want to accept arguments

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending `GetFullChannelRequest` and getting `full_chat.linked_chat_id`. If it's not None, it shows id of the channel's chat. Found that [here](https://github.com/advxrsary/opencomcheck_bot/blob/main/main.py#L154)

Comment: sorry, this one is for telethon :(