Problem with getting comments of a telegram channel message with telethon in python
I have a problem getting the comments to message of a telegram channel with the telethon python library.
I created a blank channel, added the discussbot to get the comment button under the messages, post a message and add comments to the message.
When I use the telethon library, I get the original messages of the channel but the replies attribute is None and I can't get the comments. Also I don't get the replies in the loop.
Any idea, why the replies attribut is None? how can I receive the comments?
with TelegramClient("anon", api_id, api_hash) as client:            
            channel_entity=client.get_entity("testchannel")                  
            for message in client.iter_messages(
                channel_entity, offset_date=till_date
            ):                                                   

Thanks
Marv

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77860915/4759433. Tldr, you need to get the linked channel where comments are actually sent to, and get the replies to a message on that.

Thanks for your answer. I tried the following code:
 channel_entity=client.get_entity("testchannel")            
 full_channel = client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
                       channel=channel_entity
                ))
 full_chat = full_channel.full_chat 
 for message in client.iter_messages(
     channel_entity, offset_date=till_date
 ):

I get the full_chat object but the linked_chat_id attribute is None (see debugging screenshot, I cleared the id attribute in the picture).

I added a screenshot from the telegram comments.app website with a test message in the channel and some test comments.

Any idea why the linked_chat_id is empty?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
